# Where has the JavaFX scene builder gone?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I am trying to find the elusive JavaFX scene builder so I can use it in Intellij. I am on Windows OS.

Oracle have stated that the JavaFX scene builder is included in a new download, but no matter how I search I cannot find it (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html). I think they have linked to the incorrect page and Googling for it is getting me nowhere.

I already have Java 8 SDK installed and working fine. Apparently JavaFX is now included in that, but nowhere in the Java folder can I find the scene builder and it seems to be completely missing online.

Please can anyone help? I am just wanting to write a small GUI program and it seems like JavaFX is the way to go (if it isn't then feel free to disabuse me of this notion!)

Comment: Um, so you mean there is no download? That's me stuffed :(

Comment: Sadly, I don't think so. Please have a look at my recent answer.

Comment: Well, code is out there. Check also this [link](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2015-March/016751.html)

Comment: @James_D So is the Scene Builder program being discontinued? Will they continue updating it as new versions of javaFX come out?

Comment: @NotNotLogical Oracle will not be updating it. It is now Open Sourced, but Gluon seem to be publishing builds on that open source, so best follow them I think.

Comment: I just opened a NetBeans and... no anywhere FX Scene Builder. It seems that Microsoft buy Oracle - the same ecosystem principles! Ha-ha

Comment: for latest release of Scene builder you can find it here from http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Answer (score 86, accepted):

With JDK8u40, according to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html):

> Starting with Oracle Java SE 8u40, Oracle does not provide a separate set of accompanying JavaFX Scene Builder binaries. If you would like to contribute changes, ideas or just let us know what you have done with the code, please consult the OpenJDK Community contribution guidelines and join the openjfx-dev mailing list.

You can still download the last binary at Oracle in this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html). But check this warning:

> WARNING: These versions of JavaFX Scene Builder may include components that do not contain the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.

This means it doesn't include the last changes of 8u40, like the new `Spinner` control.

**Alternatives**

The project is open source, and you can find the updated code at the OpenJFX [repo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/59b4e48b2f2e/apps/scenebuilder). So you are free to download it and build it.

Since its released under BSD license, [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-supports-scene-builder/) is offering support for an updated version of Scene Builder, and you can download an installer for your platform or an executable jar from [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download).

Besides, they have an open [repository](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder) where anybody can contribute.

Comment: But that's the source code download site, not the general availability site. I think it is just an oversight when they updated it to 8u40 (yesterday?).

Comment: They say it loud and clear: *Starting with Oracle Java SE 8u40, Oracle does not provide a separate set of accompanying JavaFX Scene Builder binaries*

Comment: OK, that's a bit of a surprise. Gluon seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Gluon, I got a jar of Scene Builder there. I suppose we will just have to wait for them to release it as an executable for use in IntelliJ. I will tweet them to see what is up and report back if I get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the binary - really glad you found it! Works fine in IntelliJ.

Comment: @JoséPereda Is Scene Builder being discontinued then? What's the deal?

Comment: @NotNotLogical I can't tell. Based on this Jira [issue](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40184), it seems the source code will be in JDK 9, which means they will make the necessary changes to keep it in sync with the new JDK. Whether they will add new JavaFX features or not, again, I can't tell. Based on the huge number of downloads from Gluon's built, I guess Gluon will try to keep it as much updated as possible, and being open [sourced](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder), anyone can contribute.

Comment: Hi everyone, it seems Oracle still didn't fix this issue. Although I'm using Java SE7, I can't find a way to download SceneBuilder. I used to have it work 2 years ago. I don't get why they suddenly removed the binaries from their website. Does anyone of you have any update about this issue? If so, please let me know.

Comment: Is anybody else having issues opening "old" fxml files with the gluon version of SceneBuilder or is it just me? Components are out of place on Gluon SceneBuilder...

Answer (score 63):

**Install JavaFx Scene Builder (Gluon) with Intellij 14 on Windows with JDK7**

*This will probably work with Java 8 as well but I am using 7 so I didn't test 8.*

I know this has been answered but this might be helpful for future Intellij users. To get scene builder to work with Intellij 14 use the following steps.

1. Install Scene Builder for Windows. [Download/Install From Here](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) (*Windows Installer (x64)*)
2. Set Scene Builder path to executable in Intellij. `File -> Settings
   -> Languages And Frameworks -> JavaFx` By default mine installed under `C:\Users\kris\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\`
   [image]
3. Open your `.fxml` file. Click on the scene builder tab.
   [image]

**UPDATE 2019:**

- The default install path appears to know be "Program Files" `C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe`
- JavaFX plugin might need to be enabled in Intellij 2019

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me too.  Am using OSX + JDK8.

Comment: On Mac, it's _IntelliJ IDEA_ -> _Preferences_. Took me forever to find.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac, in Intellij, you need to go to preferences, then type JavaFX and then do this. Please look at the attached Image.

[image]