# JavaFX Scene Builder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Where can I download JavaFX Scene Builder from? I am looking for Windows x64 version and I cannot find it.

On the official site it says that it has been moved. If I go in the place where it tells me I should find it, it's not there.

**Update:**

I am trying to use it with IDEA. Is there another options?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880785/where-is-the-javafx-scene-builder-gone/28881132#28881132).