# Netbeans doesn't find Scene Builder

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Today I wanted to start with JavaFX on Netbeans IDE (8.0.2) and JDK 1.8.0 Update 25.

My problem is that the IDE doesn't find a valid Scene Builder Home, 
but Oracle's website says that the Scene Builder is integrated in the JDK so you don't need an extra installation of it. It is also no longer available as download (scene builder).

The consequence is that i can't "open" FXML files in Netbeans.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880785/where-is-the-javafx-scene-builder-gone/28881132#28881132). You need to download Scene Builder, it's not in the JDK. With it, you can edit FXML files.

Comment: Thank you, Oracle seemed to hide the download link for SceneBuilder, but I found it already now ;)

Comment: That link gives you an old version, without the latest changes in the JDK. You may want to download the updated one from [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/)

Answer (score 3):

You can download the latest version of JavaFX Scene builder here :

http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/

then go to your netbeans, from the main menu go to: Tools --> Options --> Java -->JavaFx --> Scene Builder home ( and choose the location where you install your Scene builder

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest version of JavaFX Scene builder here :

http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/

---

Oracle is no longer supporting scene builder.

---

After installation go to **Main Menu > Tools > Options > JavaFX** tab and select the scene builder installation path and click ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the exact problem today and someway solved it..

1. Download and install according to your system (but don't download Scene Builder Kit)
   http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/

2.check for the plugin update in Your netbeans 8.0.2 [Tools-> Plugins] and deselect all other update but JAVAFX2 SCENE BUILDER and update it with the extra necessary plugin it asks.

3.Now right click the FXML, u could see the open menu. (At last solved for me)

-Regards,

BASHKAR SAMPATH