# Scenebuiler for Ubuntu: where can I find the bin?

Tags: java, scenebuilder

I'm following this [tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/). In it, you can find this sentence:

> Navigate to the JavaFX preferences. Specify the path to your Scene
>   Builder executable.

and this picture:

[image]

My question is: where can I find that file after installing JavaFX for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

SceneBuilder is not (and never was) part of the Oracle JavaFX distribution that is embedded in the Oracle Java 8 JRE/JDK binaries.  SceneBuilder is a separate download.  Oracle no longer provide binary distributions of SceneBuilder.  See: [Where has the JavaFX scene builder gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880785/where-is-the-javafx-scene-builder-gone)

Binary SceneBuilder distributions are currently provided by Gluon and may be [downloaded from the Gluon site](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/).  Gluon provide a .deb package, which is the package that you would use to install SceneBuilder on Ubuntu.  By examining the installed files of the .deb Gluon SceneBuilder distribution, you should be able to determine the location of the binary file for SceneBuilder for that distribution.

Comment: `By examining the installed files of the .deb Gluon SceneBuilder distribution, you should be able to determine the location of the binary file for SceneBuilder for that distribution.` <- That's the problem, I don't know which of them is..

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't run Ubuntu, so I can't examine the installed files of the SceneBuilder .deb.  As you are unable to determine the correct file, I suggest you contact Gluon directly to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on ubuntu, look for the installed SceneBuilder binary here:

```
/opt/scenebuilder/bin
```

note that to configure it in intellij you need to specify the path and the name of the executable included, like so:

```
/opt/scenebuilder/bin/SceneBuilder
```