# How to start Java FX Scene Builder on OSX ElCaptain

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I have installed JDK 8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

System Version: OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
```

After lots of googling I couldn't find a way to start Java FX scene Builder

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have ypi installed scenebuilder? It's not included in the JDK and the latest version is not on the oracle page, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28880785/2991525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene builder is a separate download afaik, but oracles website it horrible, so finding is is quite hard. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html

---

Some time ago i read, that gluon had taken over the development of the scene builder and I downloaded it from them.
http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/

Comment: Sorry for the temporal break down and thanks for pointing out the problem. Now it's fixed, and the link is here: http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/

Comment: Holy smokes! Thanks for fixing it so fast :O

I was planning on contacting your support about it, but didn't have a lot of time earlier and couldn't find  support email on your side very fast. So i postponed it. No need for it anymore though :D