# JavaFX - Can't add the Scene Builder to Intellij idea 2016

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to add  Scene Builder to Intellij idea 2016 by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31151376/3998402) but I just see this:
[image]

my current solution is by opening it in standalone  Scene Builder.

Comment: I don't know that [StackOverflow is really the right place for Gluon support](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company), but I can see why you asked this here given [Gluon's support page](http://gluonhq.com/support/).

Comment: Indeed, it's IntelliJ idea support more than Gluon support, and I know there are jet brains' employees viewing every question on IntelliJ-idea tag.
so I kinda hope that someone sees it and show me what's I did wrong or fix their IDE if it'ana bug.

the alternative for that is sending them emails and wait for them days respond if they even respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying some things I found that it only working with 32-bit version only not with 64-bit which I was using even if I installed Gluon's Scene Builder 64-bit.
so I just switched to IntelliJ 32-bit and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ built-in Scene Builder uses the standalone Scene Builder you have installed in your machine by scanning its Java folder, looking for the `dist.jar`.

It is recommended having the latest [version](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/#download) of Scene Builder installed.

I've just tried IntelliJ 2016.1.1 with Gluon's Scene Builder 8.1.1 and it works normally, given the limitations the embedded version has: it doesn't have menus, controller panel, custom controls, ...

The preferred way is opening your FXML files from the built in menu `Open in SceneBuilder`.

Comment: I'm already using IntelliJ 2016.1.1 with Gluon's Scene Builder 8.1.1 but it I just see a blank screen. for now I'm using  standalone Scene Builder.

Comment: Create a simple FXML file on Scene Builder first and then try to open it from IntelliJ.