# Intellij idea gluon scene builder : cannot create instance of view

Tags: gluon-mobile

I just started to play with gluon mobile and after i installed the gluon plugin on intellij idea and create my first project i encountered this problem when trying to open the primary fxml file with scene builder:

[image]

Any suggestions to solve this please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IntelliJ embedded Scene Builder can't deal with custom controls, for that you need to open the FXML file with the standalone Scene Builder application. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37088118/3956070).

Comment: I have installed the scene builder application in my windows computer and set the path to it's .exe in intellij idea but unfortunately the problem remain the same. There is however a strange fact, when i open the file with the scene builder app no problems occurs.

Comment: You need to open the FXML from the context menu (`Open in SceneBuilder`). Also make sure you have the latest version, 8.3.0.

Comment: I get it working outside the editor but why it's not working inside the editor, is this a bug ?

Comment: Can you clarify: working as in the app is running? What do you mean by "not working inside the editor"? Can't you open the FXML file with Scene Builder?

Comment: If i try to switch to scene builder mode in intellij idea i get the same screen as the screen in the post but when i open the file externally with scene builder no error is displayed and i get instead the view displayed correctly.

Comment: As I told you in my first comment: IntelliJ _embedded_ Scene Builder can't deal with any kind of custom controls. For that you need to open the FXML file with the standalone Scene Builder application.

Comment: Can you put this  as an answer with a reference so i can mark it as the right one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in other similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37088118/3956070), while IntelliJ built-in Scene Builder uses the standalone Scene Builder you have installed in your machine (by scanning its Java folder, looking for the `dist.jar`), even if you have the latest Scene Builder 8.3.0 with the Gluon panel and the Gluon custom controls, the embedded version can't deal with (any type of) custom controls.

You will have notice that this built-in version it is short of a lite version without menus, controller panel, custom controls.

Whenever you have custom controls (like `View`) you will need to open the FXML file with the standalone Scene Builder application, using the context menu option `Open in SceneBuilder`.