# Scene Builder returns error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I have installed Scene Builder (e(fx)clipse 2.4.0) by using Install New Software in Eclipse using [this link](http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/2.4.0/site). I also tried installing by the Eclipse Marketplace and both ways it gives me the error when trying to edit something it gives me this error:

```
Opening the file with SceneBuilder failed. 
Try setting the absolute path to scenebuilder in your preferences
```

I have already searched everywhere on my system for the absolute path, some say it's at:

```
/opt/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0
```

but I haven't found anything like that anywhere.

I am using:

- Eclipse 4.6.3
- Antergos - Arch Linux based distribution

Comment: AFAIK Scene Builder is not available through Eclipse Marketplace (it is not an Eclipse plugin). Surely the site you cited just installs e(fx)clipse?

Comment: @James_D when i open the market place and search for javafx it shows here xd maybe because i have already installed with the other option. but the problem isn't on how it is installed is where to find its absolute path

Comment: As I said, Scene Builder is not an eclipse plugin, and is not available via Eclipse Marketplace. All you seem to have done is install the e(fx)clipse plugin. You need to install Scene Builder separately. If you *have* already installed it, the absolute path will be exactly where you installed it....

Comment: oh, i thought they were the same thing. Thanks im gonna take a look where to find it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880785/where-has-the-javafx-scene-builder-gone

Comment: i found a package with it on arch linux AUR repositories

Comment: Make sure you  get a recent version though (latest is 8.3.0: you want at least 8.0). It's possible the repositories stopped updating when Oracle stopped supporting it (version 2.x).

Comment: AUR is very active there, the current version is `scenebuilder 8u102_b03-1`

Comment: @halfer I wasn't worried about the downvotes I found the answer myself later, without having to look any further from what people told were not mcve. So I just deleted it since the guys were more concerned about the text and not the question itself.

Comment: Well, yes, we _are_ concerned about what kinds of questions we receive here. Stack Overflow accepts a limited sub-set of questions in order to best help its wide audience. Have a look at [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to get an idea of what is accepted and what is not. Pleased you fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i mistaken e(fx)clipse with the scene builder. Now i will install the scene builder using the AUR Package `scenebuilder` and since i'm using yaourt the command will be `yaourt -Sy scenebuilder` if someone ever get the same mistake that i had, i hope this does help you.