# Scene Builder can't load custom components (Ikonli), what am I missing?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I started using Ikonli in my JavaFX application. I added it to my dependencies:

```
compile "org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:1.9.0"
compile "org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-fontawesome-pack:1.9.0"
```

and then I added it to my fxml:

```
<?import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon?>
```

But after adding that, the Scene Builder cannot longer load the file. I get this error:

[image]

The details look like this:

[image]

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/pupeno/Documents/Dashman/java/dashman/src/main/resources/web_sites_list.fxml

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:80)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleOpenFilesAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:447)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:427)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/pupeno/Documents/Dashman/java/dashman/src/main/resources/web_sites_list.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2864)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2708)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2921)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2862)
    ... 27 more
```

*Update*: I added as custom components to Scene Builder:
- ikonli-javafx.1.9.0.jar
- ikonli-fontawesome-pack-1.9.0.jar
- ikonli-core-1.9.0.jar

Two custom components appeared in the list:

[image]

but attempting to open the fxml in Scene Builder still fails with:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/pupeno/Documents/Dashman/java/dashman/src/main/resources/web_sites_list.fxml

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:80)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleOpenFilesAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:447)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:427)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/pupeno/Documents/Dashman/java/dashman/src/main/resources/web_sites_list.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2864)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2708)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2921)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2862)
    ... 27 more
```

If I open a fxml file with no ikonli components and add one, after saving it, I can't open it again, with that same error.

I found a "Show JAR Analysis Report" in Scene Builder and I'm seeing these errors, which might explain this behavior:

```
Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/AbstractIkonHandler.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more


Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/Ikon.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.kordamp.ikonli.Ikon
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.kordamp.ikonli.Ikon.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more

Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/IkonHandler.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.kordamp.ikonli.IkonHandler
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.kordamp.ikonli.IkonHandler.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more

Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/Ikonli.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.kordamp.ikonli.Ikonli
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.kordamp.ikonli.Ikonli.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more


Not a Node: org/kordamp/ikonli/IkonliIkonResolver.class

Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/javafx/FontIconConverter.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1014)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil can not access a member of class org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIconConverter with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:101)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more


Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/javafx/Icon.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.Icon
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.Icon.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more


Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/javafx/IkonResolver.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1014)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil can not access a member of class org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.IkonResolver with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:101)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more


Exception for: org/kordamp/ikonli/fontawesome/FontAwesome.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:2
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1012)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome.FontAwesome
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome.FontAwesome.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2971)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403)
    ... 13 more

Not a Node: org/kordamp/ikonli/fontawesome/FontAwesomeIkonHandler.class
```

What am I missing here? What should I do to make this work?

Comment: What about `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon`?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens not sure what you mean.

Comment: I think you need to add the jar file to scene builder also !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a custom component to SceneBuilder 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0)

Comment: You should update your SceneBuilder version. Using Gluon's SceneBuilder [8.3.0](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) allows you to import dependencies from Maven in the first place (both `org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx` and `org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-fontawesome-pack` in this case) and it also takes care of possible traversal dependencies, and the FXML file that includes a `FontIcon` object can be opened without any issue.

Comment: @JoséPereda: thanks, Gluon's Scene Builder seems to do the trick. What's the issue here? is a third party scene builder taking over?

Comment: Oracle [doesn't do releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880785/where-has-the-javafx-scene-builder-gone/28881132#28881132) anymore. Gluon not only releases SceneBuilder since then, but also includes new features, and keeps it open source ([repo](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder)).

Answer (score 2):

As of the hint of José Pereda:

1. Open Scene Builer without a fxml file.
2. Click on the little settings icon on Library (top left)
3. Open Jar/FXML Manager
4. Add the libraries
5. Then you can open the fxml file just fine.

[image: Scene Builder Library Manager]

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to solve this problem. Download ikonli-core, ikonli-javafx and ikonli-fontawesome-pack jar file from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kordamp.ikonli. Make sure to import all these three libraries into Scene Builder (Make sure you are using Scene from from Gluon) as Jose Pereda mentioned in the post above.

[image]

Go to File -> Project structure if you are using IntelliJ IDEA.
Select Platform Settings -> Global Libraries. Click on the '+' icon and import all the 3 libraries you download into your project.

[image]

[image]

Lastly, create a module-info.java file and add the required import for the FontIcon class and you are go to go!
Your module-info class should look like this:

```
module yourProjectName{
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.kordamp.iconli.core;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome;
    opens sample;
}
```