# Eclipse JavaFX Scene Builder add ButtonBar or grouped buttons to GUI

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder, java-9

I building a desktop app in Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) using JavaFX, which will be my first. I have created a file called PersonOverview.fxml and I have added the following code to my code;

```
<ButtonBar>
    <buttons>
        <Button text="New" ButtonBar.buttonData="LEFT" />
        <Button text="Save" ButtonBar.buttonData="RIGHT" />
    </buttons>
</ButtonBar>
```

JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 does not seem to recognize the element -
 **[`ButtonBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.html)**

I am wondering if there is an alternative to this. I would like to add a group of buttons to my GUI at the very bottom right of the GUI. Something like this;

[image: Grouped buttons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SceneBuilder 2.0 was the [latest release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880785/where-has-the-javafx-scene-builder-gone/28881132#28881132) from Oracle and it was before Java 8u40, which means that it doesn't contain controls like `ButtonBar` or `Spinner` that were [added](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.html) in 8u40.

To be able to work with fully JavaFX 8/9 compatible fxml files, you need SceneBuilder from Gluon. You can download your binary from [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download).

The project is still open source, you can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder), it is not only updated with the latest changes in JDKs 8 and 9, but also new features are being included.

Comment: Thanks! This worked after updating to latest release JavaFX Scene Builder 9.0.1